# Python Cloud Shell Measurement Protocol Google Analytic Universal

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to write python to run in cloud shell as a POC in Google cloud.

The objective is to use big query to get the GA client id of some users & for each row in the output send a measurement protocol event to universal analytics.

My python skills are somewhat limited and all of our dev team work in python in the cloud. So I'm stuck with it.

The code errors on line 41 when trying to send the request, but I can work out why & pythons error code are not particularly helpful.

[image]

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy


# Set up your Google Analytics tracking ID
TRACKING_ID = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1'

# Set up the BigQuery client
client = bigquery.Client()

# Set up the query to get the data from the BigQuery table
query = """
SELECT
  '2042839989.1670364010' as client_id,  
  'test' as event_category,
  'test' as event_action,
  'test' as event_label,
  0 as event_value
"""

# Run the query and get the results
results = client.query(query).result()

print(results)

# Send the event data to Google Analytics for each row in the result
for row in results:
  data = {
    'v': '1',  # Protocol version
    'tid': TRACKING_ID,  # Tracking ID
    'cid': row['client_id'],  # Anonymous client ID
    't': 'event',  # Event hit type
    'ec': row['event_category'],  # Event category
    'ea': row['event_action'],  # Event action
    'el': row['event_label'],  # Event label
    'ev': row['event_value'],  # Event value
  }

  print(data)

  proxy = ServerProxy('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect')

  response = proxy.call(data)
  
  print(response)
```

Comment: i dont know the answer to this question, but just wanted to mention that with python the most informative of the error message is the bottom part, and that is cut off from your image.

Comment: thanks updated picture I did not realise i cut it off at the end

Answer (score 0):

Did some reading & testing of other packages send measurement protocol.

Founds request package and factored that into the code

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import requests

# Set up your Google Analytics tracking ID
TRACKING_ID = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1'

# Set up the BigQuery client
client = bigquery.Client()

# Set up the query to get the data from the BigQuery table
query = """
SELECT
  '2042839989.1670364010' as client_id,  
  'audience' as event_category,
  'test' as event_action,
  'test' as event_label,
  0 as event_value
"""

# Run the query and get the results
results = client.query(query).result()

print(results)

# Send the event data to Google Analytics for each row in the result
for row in results:
  payload = {
    'v': '1',  # Protocol version
    'tid': TRACKING_ID,  # Tracking ID
    'cid': row['client_id'],  # Anonymous client ID
    'uip': '92.232.199.9', # Hardcode Manual IP address
    'ua': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36', # Hardcode User Agent
    't': 'event',  # Event hit type
    'ec': row['event_category'],  # Event category
    'ea': row['event_action'],  # Event action
    'el': row['event_label'],  # Event label
    'ev': row['event_value'],  # Event value
  }

  print(payload)

  response = requests.get('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect', params=payload)
  
  print(response)
```